# Wait for a callback to be called in an async method

Tags: c#, async-await

Say I have the following method that subscribes to an event. A callback is called when the event occurs. I would like to prevent my method to return until the callback is called, or after 10 seconds has passed.

```
public async Task<string> GetImportantString()
{
    string importantResult = null;
    await SubscribeToEvent("some event", async (message) =>
    {
        importantResult = message; // When "some event" happens, callback is called and we can set importantResult 
    }

    return message; // Only return when the callback is called, or 10 seconds have passed
}
```

The signature for `SubscribeToEvent()` is as follows:

```
public Task SubscribeToEvent(string event, Action<string> handler);
```

The way I would use method `GetImportantString()` is as follows:

```
public void SomeMethod() 
{
    // Do some things
    var importantString = await GetImportantString();
   // Do other things
}
```

The problem is that I cannot find a way to not return from `GetImportantString()` until the callback has been called. Ideally, I would like to wait until the callback has called for up to 10 seconds and return an error if the callback was not called within 10 seconds. How can I suspend the execution of `GetImportantString()` until a callback is called?

Comment: The whole point of async in `GetImportantString` would be to not block the caller thread. Normally, if that is also awaited, then execution only continues after `SubscribeToEvent` returns

Comment: A better signature for the `SubscribeToEvent` method would be: `public Task<string> SubscribeToEvent(string event, Func<string, Task<string>> handler);`. Your current signature does not allow a proper cooperation with an async delegate. The `async (message) =>` lambda in your example is `async void`, which is [something to avoid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: Btw the `async (message) =>` lambda should probably generate a warning in Visual Studio, about an `async` method that lacks an `await` operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
public async Task<string> GetImportantString()
{
    string importantResult = null;
    using (var sph = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1))
    {
        await SubscribeToEvent("some event", (message) =>
        {
            importantResult = message; // When "some event" happens, callback is called and we can set importantResult
            try
            {
                sph.Release();
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException){}
        });

        var t = sph.WaitAsync();

        if (await Task.WhenAny(t, Task.Delay(10000)) == t)
        {
            return importantResult;
        }
    }
    throw new TimeoutException(); // whatever you want to do here
}
```

We use a `SemaphoreSlim` to signal when the string is set.

At that point, we await on `Task.WhenAny` which lets us know when either the Semaphore releases or a delay-task elapses. If the Semaphore releases, we can safely assume the string has been set and return it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, the `Task` returned by `SubscribeToEvent()` does not indicate if the callback was called, it only indicates if you have subscribed to the event. Currently, the `Task` returned by `SubscribeToEvent` resolves almost instantly, but the actual callback is called 5 seconds later as the event takes much longer to happen.

Comment: @ThomasFromUganda -- try that out -- I haven't tested it.

Comment: That solution never crossed my mind. Thanks!

Comment: The line `sph.Release();` may produce an unhandled `ObjectDisposedException`

Comment: Updated answer to put in @Ackdari's suggestion.